# Cypress: Check if element exists & throw an exception when element doesn't

Tags: testing, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to check if an element exists or not. If the element exists, I want to click on the button X, I want to click on the button Y.

However, when the element does not exist Cypress throws an exception and it stops the test.

[image]

**Code Sample:**

```js
let elementKey = '#up-picker'
Cypress.get('body').then($res=>{
  if($res.find(elementKey).length>0){
   // click on button X
  }else{
    // click on button Y
  }
})
```

I have an element with this `id`, but sometimes because the logic in the UI changes it, Cypress can find this element.

I checked more posts in Stackoverflow and no answer works for me.

Comment: @Mansprof would increasing the timeout help you with your case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's working for my tests (close to your example):

```
cy.get('body').then($body => {
  if ($body.find('your-selector').length) {
    // do stuff
  }
});
```